# Using PdfStamper to add a rectangle

Tags: c#, itext

Hi I have a pdf I created using itextsharp.

Using pdfreader I am reading the created pdf into a pdfstamper.

Now I am trying to use the pdfstamper to add a black rectangle the size of the page on all pages. How do i do this?

Also I cannot use document to add the rectangle because the stream is close!

```
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(output.ToArray());
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, stream);

    for (int x = 0; x < stamper.Reader.NumberOfPages; x++)
    {
        Rectangle rectangle = document.PageSize;
        rectangle.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(0, 0, 0);
        //stamper.Writer.AcroForm.
        //document.Add(rectangle);
    }

    output.Close();
    pdfReader.Close();
    stamper.Close();
```

Comment: Where is document coming into scope?  I don't see it in your example code.  Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583629/how-can-i-insert-an-image-with-itextsharp-in-an-existing-pdf  It's about images, but may give you the help you need.

Comment: The document can into the scope when creating a header for the pdf using PDFDocument and putting it in a memorystream and then using PDFWriter to create the pdf. When using PDFReader you cannot have the document because creation of the document is not complete until you close the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to draw using the `PdfStamper` then you need to use the `PdfContentByte` which you can get by calling `stamper.GetOverContent(pageNum)`. There's a specific command on that object called `Rectangle` which does exactly what you want it to do. Also, remember that pages within a PDF start numbering at one and not zero.

Below is a full working C# 2010 WinForm app targeting iTextSharp 5.1.1.0 that should do what you're looking for, I think. You'll need to modify it to support the `MemoryStream` but that should be pretty easy.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string inputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "input.pdf");
            string outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "output.pdf");

            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputFile);
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, fs))
                {
                    int PageCount = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
                    for (int x = 1; x <= PageCount; x++)
                    {
                        PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(x);
                        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rectangle = pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(x);
                        rectangle.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.BLACK;
                        cb.Rectangle(rectangle);
                    }
                }
            }

            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just had to make some changes to suit a web application.