# How to add an Image to a PDF document?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext, reportviewer

I am using iTextSharp to join multiple pdfs together that are from microsofts report viewer.  page.AddImage(image__1) in the code below is throwing an error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I am not seeing what is set to nothing. Is there a different way that I can join reports from the report viewer and add a watermark image?

```
    mybytes = MSRptViewer1.LocalReport.Render("PDF", Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
    reader = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(mybytes)
    numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages
    currentPageNumber = 0

    Dim imageFile As String = Server.MapPath("WaterMark.png")
    Dim buffer As Byte() = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imageFile)
    Dim image__1 As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(buffer)
    image__1.SetAbsolutePosition(100, 100)

    Do While (currentPageNumber < numberOfPages)
        currentPageNumber += 1
        doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.LETTER)
        doc.NewPage()

        page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, currentPageNumber)
        page.AddImage(image__1)

        rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(currentPageNumber)
        If (rotation = 90) Or (rotation = 270) Then
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(currentPageNumber).Height)
        Else
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F, 0, 0)
        End If
    Loop
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I insert an image with iTextSharp in an existing PDF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583629/how-can-i-insert-an-image-with-itextsharp-in-an-existing-pdf)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have asked my Publisher, Manning Publications, to offer [chapter 6 of my book](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) for free. I know this chapter only shows you examples in Java, but all the examples were [ported to C#](http://tinyurl.com/iiacsCH06) for your convenience.

If you read this chapter, you'll find out that you're making the following mistakes:

1. You are using `PdfReader`/`PdfWriter` to add content to an existing document instead of `PdfReader`/`PdfStamper`. If you want a nice watermark example, take a look at the ManipulatePdf method in the [StampStationery.cs](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter06/StampStationery.cs) example. Replace `background.addTemplate()` with `background.addImage()` to add an image instead of a background page taken from another PDF. You'll also learn more about using an image as a watermark here: [How to add a watermark to a PDF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522965/how-to-add-a-watermark-to-a-pdf-file)
2. You are using `PdfReader`/`PdfWriter` to concatenate existing documents instead of `PdfCopy`. By doing so, you risk all kinds of problems: e.g. parts of pages being cut off, links being removed, annotations getting lost,... Please read my answer to this question: [How to merge documents correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731439/how-to-merge-documents-correctly)
3. You are ignoring the fact that `PdfImportedPage` is read-only. You can only add content in the context of `PdfCopy` after creating a `PageStamp` object. Please take a look at the [ConcatenateStamp.cs](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter06/ConcatenateStamp.cs) example.

Summarized: your question is more or less a duplicate of (a combination of) other questions answered before on StackOverflow. It seems that you copy/pasted some code from a source that isn't one of the official sources of documentation.

Comment: Strange. SO says it was asked yesterday. It's probably a fluke. Thanks for accepting the answer anyway.

Comment: It was asked then, but that code for concatenating documents has been used for over a year in the product I am working on

Comment: Aha, I misunderstood your remark. Anyway: if it's a commercial product you're working on, please check if you have a support contract with iText Software. You may want to post questions like that to our support team.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $data = file_get_contents('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56c775ad27d4bd3fdb24775d/t/5a8b201324a694d7071662ee/1519067160925/dummy+logo.jpg');
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
?>
```

this method for image convert to base64  format

```
<?php echo '<div class="company-logo"><img src="'.$base64.'"  alt="base" /></div>'; ?>
```

or

```
<img src="<?php echo $base64; ?>"  alt="base" />
```