# How to merge documents correctly?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have the following problem when printing the pdf file after merge, the pdf documents get cut off.
Sometimes this happens because the documents aren't 8.5 x 11
they might be like 11 x 17.

Can we make it detect the page size and then use that same page size for those documents?
Or, if not, is it possible to have it fit to page?

Following is the code:

```
package com.sumit.program;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class MergePdf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<InputStream> pdfs = new ArrayList<InputStream>();

            pdfs.add(new FileInputStream("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Sumit\\Desktop\\NewEcnProject\\Document1.pdf"));
            pdfs.add(new FileInputStream("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Sumit\\Desktop\\NewEcnProject\\Landscape.pdf"));           
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Sumit\\Desktop\\NewEcnProject\\merge1.pdf");
            MergePdf.concatPDFs(pdfs, output, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void concatPDFs(List<InputStream> streamOfPDFFiles,
            OutputStream outputStream, boolean paginate) {

        Document document = new Document();
        try {
            List<InputStream> pdfs = streamOfPDFFiles;
            List<PdfReader> readers = new ArrayList<PdfReader>();
            int totalPages = 0;
            Iterator<InputStream> iteratorPDFs = pdfs.iterator();

            // Create Readers for the pdfs.
            int i=1;
            while (iteratorPDFs.hasNext()) {
                InputStream pdf = iteratorPDFs.next();
                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdf);
                System.out.println("Page size is "+pdfReader.getPageSize(1));
                readers.add(pdfReader);
                totalPages += pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
                i++;
            }
            // Create a writer for the outputstream
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
            writer.setCompressionLevel(9);
            document.open();
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,
                    BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent(); // Holds the PDF data

            PdfImportedPage page;
            int currentPageNumber = 0;
            int pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
            Iterator<PdfReader> iteratorPDFReader = readers.iterator();

            // Loop through the PDF files and add to the output.
            while (iteratorPDFReader.hasNext()) {
                PdfReader pdfReader = iteratorPDFReader.next();

                // Create a new page in the target for each source page.
                System.out.println("No. of pages "+pdfReader.getNumberOfPages());
               i=0;
                while (pageOfCurrentReaderPDF < pdfReader.getNumberOfPages()) {
                    Rectangle r=pdfReader.getPageSize(pdfReader.getPageN(pageOfCurrentReaderPDF+1));
                    if(r.getWidth()==792.0 && r.getHeight()==612.0)
                        document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
                    else
                        document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
                    document.newPage();
                    pageOfCurrentReaderPDF++;
                    currentPageNumber++;
                    i++;

                    page = writer.getImportedPage(pdfReader,
                            pageOfCurrentReaderPDF);
                    System.out.println("Width is "+page.getWidth());
                    System.out.println("Height is "+page.getHeight());
                    cb.newlineText();
                    cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);

                    // Code for pagination.
                    if (paginate) {
                        cb.beginText();
                        cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 9);
                        cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, ""
                                + currentPageNumber + " of " + totalPages, 520,
                                5, 0);
                        cb.endText();
                    }
                }
                pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            document.close();
            outputStream.close();
            System.out.println("Merging of Pdfs is done.......");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (document.isOpen())
                document.close();
            try {
                if (outputStream != null)
                    outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Using the `Document` and `PdfWriter` class in combination with the `addTemplate()` method to merge documents is a bad idea. That's not what the `addTemplate()` method is meant for. You have explicitly or implicitly defined the page size for the `Document` you are working with. With the `addTemplate()` method, you add `PdfImportedPage` instances, and

- when you add a new page with the same page size and rotation, you throw away all interactivity that exists in that page, but otherwise all is well,
- when you add a new page with a different page size and rotation, you get the result you describe. Because of the difference in size, the imported page and the new page do not match. Parts get cut off, extra margins appear, rotations are different, etc.

This is all explained in [chapter 6 of my book](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter2.pdf). You should use `PdfCopy` instead of `PdfWriter`. See for instance the [FillFlattenMerge2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/reporting/FillFlattenMerge2) example:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
document.open();
PdfReader reader;
String line = br.readLine();
// loop over readers
    // add the PDF to PdfCopy
    reader = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
    copy.addDocument(reader);
    reader.close();
// end loop
document.close();
```

In your case, you also need to add page numbers, you can do this in a second go, as is done in the [StampPageXofY](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper/StampPageXofY) example:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
PdfContentByte pagecontent;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ) {
    pagecontent = stamper.getOverContent(++i);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(pagecontent, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
            new Phrase(String.format("page %s of %s", i, n)), 559, 806, 0);
}
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

Or you can add them while merging, as is done in the [MergeWithToc](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/merge/MergeWithToc) example.

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
PageStamp stamp;
document.open();
int n;
int pageNo = 0;
PdfImportedPage page;
Chunk chunk;
for (Map.Entry<String, PdfReader> entry : filesToMerge.entrySet()) {
    n = entry.getValue().getNumberOfPages();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ) {
        pageNo++;
        page = copy.getImportedPage(entry.getValue(), ++i);
        stamp = copy.createPageStamp(page);
        chunk = new Chunk(String.format("Page %d", pageNo));
        if (i == 1)
            chunk.setLocalDestination("p" + pageNo);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(stamp.getUnderContent(),
                Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase(chunk),
                559, 810, 0);
        stamp.alterContents();
        copy.addPage(page);
    }
}
document.close();
for (PdfReader r : filesToMerge.values()) {
    r.close();
}
reader.close();
```

I strongly advise against using `PdfWriter` to merge documents! It's not impossible if you change the page size and the rotation of the page in the `Document` class, but you're making it harder on yourself. Moreover: using `PdfWriter` also throws away all interactivity (links, annotations,...) that exists in the pages you're merging. Your customer may experience that as a bug.

Comment: Thanks it is working For me but i want to add Some text to every copied page at the Bottom like "Page No 1". how can i do?

Comment: one more thing i want to add new page in the middle after any page, how can i do this?

Comment: Adding something to every copied page is explained in my answer: use `PageStamp`. Adding a new page in the middle after any page: please explain what you mean, because the question isn't clear. Create a new question for this. Comments aren't the place to add new questions. If the answer answered the question: please accept it. If you have more questions, please create a new question.