# Digital signature is not copied with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, split, itext

I have this method that split a pdf of many pages into many files for each page.
I noticed that if a pdf contains a digital signature or a shape(rectangle for example) iTextsharp don't copy those things into the splitted file.
Are there any reason about it?
Am I missing something here?

```
 private static void MultipleSplitPdf(IResult result, List<string> fileNames, string directoryforsplit, out List<string> outFileNames)
    {

    if (fileNames.Count == 0)
    {
        result.SetError("no files!");
        outFileNames = null;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            outFileNames = new List<string>();

            if (FileManager.DeleteDir(result, directoryforsplit) == false)
                return;
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo;
            if (FileManager.GetDirectory(result, directoryforsplit, out dirInfo) == false)
                return;

            int counter = 1;
            foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
            {
                // we create a reader for a certain document
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileName);
                // we retrieve the total number of pages
                int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
                //Console.WriteLine("There are " + n + " pages in the original file.");

                int pagenumber = n;

                //if (pagenumber == 1)
                //{
                //    FileInfo a = new FileInfo(fileName);
                //    a.CopyTo(directoryforsplit);
                //}

                //else
                    for (int i = 1; i <= pagenumber; i++)
                    {
                        iTextSharp.text.Document document1 = new iTextSharp.text.Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i));
                        string splittedFilePath = directoryforsplit + "\\Split" + counter.ToString() + ".pdf";
                        PdfWriter writer1 = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document1, new FileStream(splittedFilePath, FileMode.Create));
                        document1.Open();
                        PdfContentByte cb1 = writer1.DirectContent;
                        PdfImportedPage page;

                        int rotation;

                        document1.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i));
                        document1.NewPage();
                        page = writer1.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                        rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i);
                        if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
                        {
                            cb1.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cb1.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                        }
                        counter++;
                        document1.Close();
                    }
            }
            // step 1: creation of a document-object

            //iTextSharp.text.Document document2 = new iTextSharp.text.Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pagenumber));
            // step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document

            //PdfWriter writer2 = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document2, new FileStream(args[2], FileMode.Create));
            // step 3: we open the document

            //document2.Open();
            //PdfContentByte cb2 = writer2.DirectContent;


            // step 4: we add content
            //while (i < pagenumber - 1)
            //{

            //}
            //while (i < n)
            //{
            //    i++;
            //    document2.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i));
            //    document2.NewPage();
            //    page = writer2.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
            //    rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i);
            //    if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
            //    {
            //        cb2.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height);
            //    }
            //    else
            //    {
            //        cb2.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
            //    }
            //    Console.WriteLine("Processed page " + i);
            //}
            //// step 5: we close the document

            //document2.Close();
            FileInfo[] wordFiles = dirInfo.GetFiles();

            foreach (var item in wordFiles.OrderBy(i => i.LastWriteTime))
                outFileNames.Add(dirInfo.FullName + "\\" + item.Name);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            outFileNames = null;
            result.SetError(e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are doing it wrong! Please read [Chapter 6](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) of iText in Action and you'll discover that you should use `PdfStamper` or `PdfCopy`, **NOT** a combination of `Document`/`PdfWriter` to split or merge documents. **As documented, your code removes all interactive features!** See [How to merge documents correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731439/how-to-merge-documents-correctly) and read the documentation! This book is available for free: [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html).
2. Your PDF document is **digitally signed**. This means that **you can not extract pages from it** and **you can not merge it with another document** without breaking the digital signature. Read [how to add blank page in digitally signed pdf using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710439/how-to-add-blank-page-in-digitally-signed-pdf-using-java) to find out the error in your design. You are trying to do something that is not done (in general, not limited to iText or iTextSharp).