# How to insert an image into a pdf document with C#?

Tags: c#, image, pdf

I m searching for a way with a free dll library modify a pdf.
I want to insert an image to a certain position into a pdf document.

I already found iTextSharp, but this only add a page before my document.

How do I insert an image to specific position?

```cs
var reader = new PdfReader(inputPdfStream);
var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdfStream);
var pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(inputImageStream);
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle r_01 = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(30,10);
PdfContentByte page1 = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
image.SetAbsolutePosition(0,0);
page1.AddImage(image);
stamper.Close();
```

Comment: You *"want to insert an image to a certain position"*, in your code do `image.SetAbsolutePosition(0,0)`, and have no idea what to try next? Furthermore, you say *"this only add a page before my document"* but the code you show does not add a page at all.

Comment: Thank you for this comment , i just put a code that was good actually. I played via the SetAbsP parameter and this is working now. I just cannot resize the image i m putting

Comment: You may want to look at the `ScaleAbsolute`, `ScalePercent`, and `ScaleToFit` overloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ITextSharp is a good one, and you can actually add images to existing pages. We use it to auto-generate our product templates and add QR codes.

See Darin Dimitrov's answer here:
[How can I insert an image with iTextSharp in an existing PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583629/how-can-i-insert-an-image-with-itextsharp-in-an-existing-pdf)