# PDF Manipulation with Adobe's Form Input Fields

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf, pdf-manipulation

I am trying to simplify a process where I currently use my hand calculations of X & Y Co-Ordinates of each value. Which works fine, but is causing me a lot of pain as I have to do quite a number of PDF's.

I know that I can open a PDF and insert "input fields" within Adobe Acrobat Pro, which it would be great if I could use PHP to connect to those input fields and insert a value from a PHP Form.

WORKFLOW::

PHP FORM >>> PHP PROCESSING ENGINE >>> TO FINAL PDF WITH FORM VALUES IN THE LOCATION OF THE ADOBE INPUT FIELDS.

If someone has some information on something like this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a direct answer to your question, but maybe it will save you some time.

We tried doing something similar and ended up abandoning the idea of doing this programatically ourselves.  It was much more cost-efficient to just buy this product: http://www.evermap.com/automailmerge.asp?gclid=CPfW44DNsKYCFULNKgodyV6Rnw

as the cost of paying me to write similar functionality was not a good ROI.

However, a similar (but not exact duplicate) qhestion has been asked here, and you may be able to get ideas from it.

[How to do mail merge on top of a PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356502/how-to-do-mail-merge-on-top-of-a-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP script could generate an FDF that your PDF could import and obtain values from.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, which I have been trying to test... and I am able to create the FDF file, but I cannot get them to MERGE together. But apparently http://www.fpdf.org/ >> Scripts >> Form Filling. But I am unable to get them to work with New Forms rather than just the testing files... And there is zero documentation on issues or anything...